# unexpected sample behavior

Tags: r, random, simulation, sample

I am currently running a small simulation and am irritated by the results.
This is my code:

```
ground_truth <- c("coke", "zero", "light", "zero")
options <- c("zero", "coke", "light")
random_guess<- lapply(1:10000, function(x){
  first <- sample(options, 1)
  rest <- sample(options, 3)
  return(c(first, rest))
})
final_res <- lapply(random_guess, function(k) {
    sum(k == ground_truth)
}) %>% unlist()
table(final_res)
```

I noticed that no matter how often I generate random guesses, the code never returns a perfect match with the ground truth which seemes unlikely (impossible). I made a small adjustment to the code and changed `return(c(first,rest))` `return(c(rest, first))` and now i do get from time to time a full match with the ground truth. However this really confuses me since I thought everything is picked randomly anyway. Doing the following change `return(sample(c(first,rest)))` also returns the correct results.

Any insights into why this is happening are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ground truth is

```
"coke" then "zero", "light", "zero"
```

Your random guess chooses one of "zero", "coke", "light" and then it randomly shuffles those values. So your last three values is come permutation of those three. But you have "zero" twice in your "ground truth". `sample` by default will never pick a value twice. Did you want to sample with replacement? If so, add `rest <- sample(options, 3, replace=TRUE)` but that means you may have something like "coke", "zero", "zero", "zero". So see if that makes sense with your simulation. It's not clear exactly what type of process you are trying to model. If you change to `return(c(rest, first))` that means there will at least be a chance that you will get zero twice in the last three which can never happen just by shuffling `options`

Your random guesses are not that random because the last three values will never be duplicated. In order to mix things up, try something like this instead

```
random_guess <- lapply(1:10000, function(x){
    dup_value <- sample(options,1)
    # add dup with options and shuffle
    sample(c(dup_value, options))
})
```

Comment: Im afraid I cant follow. I do want exactly one of the options to occure twice (which one is random). I know that sample doesnt use replacement by default, this is why I use 2 sample statements and then concatenate the results. The order of the guesses is important too. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, order matters!

Comment: So you want a random sample of the three where one repeats twice? Then shuffle the values. you can use `return(sample(c(first,rest)))` or just `return(sample(c(sample(options,1), options))`

Comment: Yeah, I know. My question is however, why I have to call `sample(c(first, rest))` instead of just `c(first, rest)`, i.e. why the results differ. Because both `first` and `rest` should already be "random"

Comment: They are not "random". I'veupdate the question with a correct random_guess function. Because you pick 1 value, and then just concatenate a permutation of the options to the end, the last three values will never have a duplicate with your original method.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you very much